# Read and Write files from 'fs' not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs

I am trying to build a script which read and write some files. The functions are working fine but I am having trouble making the read/write functions asynchronously. The main problem I have is that I am trying to write a file and then I am trying to import it.
For example: given these two functions, the first one is writing to `./myFile.js` and the second function is trying to import the file like this:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
const myFile = require('./myFile')

async function writeMyFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.promises.readFile('./myFile.js', 'utf8').then((file) => {

        const replacedData = file + 'newLine'

            fs.promises
                .writeFile('./myFile.js', replacedData)
                .then(() => resolve('Writted'))
                .catch(() => reject('Error'));
        });
    });
}

function importMyFile() {
    console.log(myFile) // this is always empty
}

await writeMyFile()
importMyFile()
```

The thing is that I can see `myFile` is being written correctly, but I cannot see it in the `importMyFile` function. When I try these functions separately it works (executing the first one and then the second one)

I tried the following:

- Using the `promise` functions from `fs` library: `fs.promises.readFile()` and `fs.promises.writeFile()` (example above)
- Returning a Promise which resolves when `writeMyFile` ends. (example above)
- Importing the file directly in the `readMyFile` function like this:

```js
function importMyFile() {
    const myFile = require('./myFile')
    console.log(myFile) // this is always empty
}
```

- Without returning new Promise like this:

```js
async function writeMyFile() {
    const file = await fs.promises.readFile('./myFile.js', 'utf8')

    const replacedData = file + 'newLine'

    await fs.promises.writeFile('./myFile.js', replacedData)
}
```

I also see that in the console, the order of the logs are these:

```sh
'Writted'
{} //empty file
```

Keep in mind that this is a simplified version of my case.

**EDIT** the file I am trying to write and import looks like this ALWAYS:

```js
module.exports = []
```

And the it is populated, it looks like this:

```js
const myModule = {
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname'
}

module.exports = [myModule]
```

I hope someone knows what is going on here. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need async AND a promise. `async` makes the promise for you, so the await finishes after promise is made, but before the write is complete

Comment: I already tried without returning a `Promise` -> `await fs.promises.readFile(...)` and `await fs.promises.writeFile(..)` but nothing changes

Comment: I also don't know that `require` returns anything useful.  And, does the file already exist? Why read it before writing it? If it doesn't exist it won't get written

Comment: The file always exists. I will clarify my code sample.

Comment: `require` returns `module.exports`. if you don't have any exports in **myFile.js**, it will return an empty object.

Comment: That file always has `module.exports` in it. I updated code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `require` is different than `readFile`. Using `require` loads the .js file as a module and brings in its exported elements for use in your code. If you're just interested in printing out the text inside of the .js file, then use `fs.readFileSync` to do so (you don't need promises if you use the synchronous version of the call).

The code you have will add the string "newLine" to the end of the file, but if your intent was to add an actual newline it should be adding "\n" instead.

A simpler version of your code might look like this:

```js
function writeMyFile() {
  const file = fs.readFileSync('./myFile.js', 'utf8');
  const replacedData = file + '\n';
  fs.writeFileSync('./myFile.js', replacedData);
  return 'Written';
}

function importMyFile() {
  // actually read the file instead of using require()
  const file = fs.readFileSync('./myFile.js', 'utf8');
  console.log(file);
}

writeMyFile()
importMyFile()
```

Since no asynchronous calls are made, there's no need for promises or awaiting.

If you did intend to use the .js code inside, and it's important to use `require` then note that once you load it that way into memory, it does not get refreshed after the file on disk changes.  Even if you call `require` a subsequent time it will be smart and say "oh, I already have that one in memory" and not reload it.  So delay calling `require('./myFile')` until after any necessary changes are made and put the `require` statement inside of `importMyFile()`.

Comment: There we go.. You got it :) I was importing './myFile' more than once in my script. So even if I imported it inside the function it was loading it from the memory. Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
await writeMyFile()
importMyFile()
```

Has to be inside an async function.

For example, calling them like this, and this should work.

```
(async ()=>{

await writeMyFile()
importMyFile()

})()
```

Also the output, {} means that there is no module exported from myfile.js.

Edit:
The "myFile" variable is containing old data. As it was imported at the beginning of execution. The `importMyFile` should re import myfile.js.

```
function importMyFile() {
    myFile = require('./myFile')
    console.log(myFile)  
}
```

After this the new changes by the `writeMyFile` will be shown in the console, if the function changed `myfile.js`'s export.

Comment: They are in an async function already.